# Label and link behavior on the same element

Tags: html, hyperlink, click, label

Is it possible to use functional `label` and `hyperlink` on the same text? Basically, I want to toggle checkbox and scroll to target element, with one click and with **HTML only**.

However, it seems only one behavior (`label` OR `a`) could work at the time:

```html
<label for="box"><a href="#target">Go to target</a>
  <input type="checkbox" id="box">
</label>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<h1 id="target">Target</h1>
```

Maybe it is not possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<label id='label' for="box" href="#target" onclick='document.location = document.getElementById("label").getAttribute("href");'>Go to target
  <input type="checkbox" id="box">
</label>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<h1 id="target">Target</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I am looking for HTML only solution.

Comment: Why ? This solution works with all browsers, it's native javascript... I'm almost sure that there is any way to do that only with HTML, because the solution you need use events, <a> elements have a native click event that allow you to reach the href link, but label haven't that kind of native events

Comment: I know, but the requirement is that the page is functional without any scripts :(